# SQL Server 2008 column collation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, collation

I am inserting data to tables using dynamic SQL:

```
SET @Profiles = N'SELECT ''' + @var1 + ''' as col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
        FROM ' + @TableName + 'tbl1'

INSERT INTO
table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7)
EXEC (@Profiles)
```

Above query is in stored procedure, which is run by job.

I noticed when job is running the data with Japanese characters are inserted properly but when job is completed and I make select on inserted table it returns '?' instead of Japanese characters. I am using collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and my column data type is `nvarchar`. I also tried to change the collation but even with Japanese collation it returns '?'. Do you know how I can handle this?

EDIT 1
I forgot to add that the stored procedure resides in SSIS package. Maybe it can help.

Comment: Are you dealing with `NVARCHAR` data types through every step?  For example, are you using a `VARCHAR` variable or selecting data from `VARCHAR` columns before it's inserted?

Comment: Source and destination columns data types and its sizes are the same. Also when I run the stored procedure manually it is ok. The problem occurs when I run the stored procedure from the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. I have a function at last step of the SSIS package which removes non-printable white characters and this function parameter was varchar instead of nvarchar. I changed it to nvarchar and it is ok now.